# Index-file to module-instance interaction

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, modularity

I am making a computer system which I have broken down into several smaller parts.

From a given experience, it is crucial in software development to keep systems small.

In order to do that I am implementing a module which serves a specific purpose, all and by itself without having any idea what the rest of the system is doing. (ideal)

So this module goes there and does its thing, and when an event occurs in an instance of this module, I want the index file to become aware of that happening.
I do not want this module to communicate directly to the other modules, as they should not communicate with each other, thereby decreasing dependencies within the system.

Now, I have made the instance and the instance does everything right,
but when an event occurs in this instance, how do I get that information over to the index file?

An event of this instance is implemented in the following manner:
`the_div.addEventListener('mousedown',this.react_to_mouse_down_function);`

And here its  a question how its best to get this happening to the index file, I can do in the index file:
`the_div.addEventListener('click', the_function);`

but that forces the index file to be aware of things going on in the instance because
the instance has children which each has event detector and their numbers can grow and shrink and god knows what.
It would be best if the index file wouldn't need to understand how the instance of the module works, and thereby not needing to be generating new event listeners on the fly as the instance is living.

How is it best to setup the interaction between the index file and this instance?

Comment: try http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/, one of the wide used libs to implement pub/sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to have a designated module called 'messages', and it takes care of receiving event driving messages from instances.

An instance of the message module is made global and named 'imessages'. And each module, when an event within it occurs, checks if it has  access to the global 'imessage' object, and if it does and the imessage object contains a function with the same name as the given event, it calls that function and sends relevant information as arguments.

The given message function is now defined in the index file in a designated message module, relieving this module of any further interaction with the outside world.
Modules with this functionality need now not communicate with any other concrete modules. Just the index file.

It just needs to be stated in the API of each module applying this, how this dependency decreasing functionality of it works.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a pub/sub problem. This would let the module publish a specific custom event when state changes and the index (or any other module) can subscribe to that event if needed. The module does not communicate with anything besides the pub/sub controller.

Here is a good link: 
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

I find myself referring to various sections of this page often.